# Goroutine called in a loop on function with pointer overwrites value?

Tags: go

I have just started playing with Go and stumbled upon problem how the pointers are handled in this language.

I have such code and can`t figure out how to fix it to get the correct response.

Changing `func (me *Str) Start()` to `func (me Str) Start()` fixes the problem, but I need this as reference to write this structure (it will have channel in it).

Sample code (https://play.golang.org/p/EsPejyCrX7):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg1 sync.WaitGroup

type Str struct {
    id int
}

func (me *Str) Start() {
    wg1.Add(1)
    fmt.Println("F1 ", me)
    go me.startFn()
}

func (me *Str) startFn() {
    defer wg1.Done()
    fmt.Println("F2 ", me)
}

func main() {
    Fl2 := []Str{
        {1},
        {2},
        {3},
    }

    for _, fl := range Fl2 {
        fl.Start()
    }
    wg1.Wait()
}
```

Response:

```
F1  &{1}
F1  &{2}
F1  &{3}
F2  &{3}
F2  &{3}
F2  &{3}
```

Expected response (F2 can be random):

```
F1  &{1}
F1  &{2}
F1  &{3}
F2  &{3}
F2  &{2}
F2  &{1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using goroutines on loop iterator variables is a common mistake.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes)

Call `.Start` on the element of `Fl2` by the range index, instead of the range value ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T7LzoWSscv)):

```
for i := range Fl2 {
    Fl2[i].Start()
}
```

However, the output might still not become exactly as you expect,
due to the scheduling of the goroutines,
for example it might be like this:

```
F1  &{1}
F1  &{2}
F1  &{3}
F2  &{3}
F2  &{1}
F2  &{2}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. Are you able to explain why changing to (&fl).Start() does not fix it? I though in Go it will return me the underlying structure.